# Python2 versus Python3 post request

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, urllib

I've looked at seemingly all the other python3 urllib posts and nothing seems to work.

I have a Django (v1.11.1, using Python2) application that should be accepting POST requests (e.g. sending it some JSON data); it works in python2 using urllib/urllib2, but with python3 (and urllib) I cannot get it to send a request that Django understands.  Looking for some help in getting this sorted.

My Django view function:

```
def update_db(request):print dir(request)
    print request.POST
    return HttpResponse('Thanks for visiting.')
```

Here's a working request in Python2:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

d={'foo': 1, 'bar': 2} 
data = urllib.urlencode(d)
req = urllib2.Request(url, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req, data=data) # works!
```

Looking at the logs in my Django app I see that it understood the request:

```
<QueryDict: {u'foo': [u'1'], u'bar': [u'2']}>
```

Now, for Python3 here's my request method:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json

d={'foo': 1, 'bar': 2} 
data = json.dumps(d).encode('utf8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, 
                         data=data, 
                         headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

And my Django log shows:

```
<QueryDict: {}>
```

Django also reports that `request.method` was indeed `POST`, but for whatever reason it's not understanding the actual JSON I'm sending as part of the post request.  I also tried the `requests` library, as suggested in other threads, but nothing seems to work-- I'm always getting blank for the POST contents.  Finally, I also tried `ascii` in the encode method (instead of the utf8 shown).

Any tips?  Is there a way I can inspect the outgoing request that urllib is actually making to the url?  Thanks!

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments below, I was not understanding the actual content I was sending.  My working version for Python3 now reads:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

d={'foo': 1, 'bar': 2} 
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(d).encode('utf8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

I may eventually upgrade to the `requests` library, but at least this works now.

Comment: In the first case you're sending urlencoded data, in the second json data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first snippet is confusing. You claim to be sending JSON, but you're not; you're sending standard form-encoded data. This is what Django understands by default, anyway.

There doesn't seem to be any reason why you wouldn't do the same in Python 3 though. Why serialise to JSON? Just do:

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(d)
```

And drop the headers in both circumstances, since you're not sending JSON.

Finally, just use `requests`.

Comment: Ah, thanks!
I had previously tried what you suggested and it complained with `TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.`  So I abandoned that track.  However, once I chained on the `encode` method, it worked.  For anyone else's benefit, I added the working solution above.